# c++ reading issue with \0

Tags: c++, ifstream

Good Morning,

I've written a little program in c++ that reads some `csv` and `txt` files and then compare them with some rules.

My Problem is that the export has some `'\0'` after every letter and i can't change the export.

So I'm trying to read the File and remove the `'\0'`

At the moment i'm doing this with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    ifstream QuelleExport;
    string temp;
    int found;
    vector<InstitutionsDaten> vecInstitutionsDaten;

    //Reading the Path out of a Text File and storing it into 'QuelleExport'
    found = temp.find("PfadExport=");
    if (found > 0)
    {
        cout << "Der Export wird aus folgender Datei ausgelesen: " << endl;
        QuelleExport = Allgemein::lesenöffnen(temp.replace(0, temp.find_first_of("= ") + 2, ""));
     }
     while (getline(QuelleInstitutionsDaten, temp))
     {
         try 
         {
             if (temp != "")
             {
                 remove(temp.begin(), temp.end(), '\0');
                 InstitutionsDaten tempClass(temp);

                 vecInstitutionsDaten.push_back(tempClass);
                 temp.clear();
             }
         }
         catch (...)
         {

         }
     }
}
```

The replacement works often but not every time and also it seams like the string temp sometimes has data which shouldn't be there.

Is there any possibility to remove all `c_str` escape chars without just deleting them or do you've a other solution?

Comment: It means the file is using a multi-byte character encoding.

Comment: Open files in binary mode

Comment: Did you copy-paste a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into the question? Or did you rewrite the code by hand in the question? Always copy-paste actual code that exhibits the problem you have, don't rewrite. I wonder because your code as you show it will not build. If you rewrite code by hand instead of copy-pasting it you might add other error that distracts from your real problem, or you might actually fix the problem without realizing it making the question pretty much worthless.

Comment: @M.M the escape chars should also be there while reading the file in binary or?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i've copied the relevant stuff since my main program has 396 lines and also 4 classes.
if you want i can include the whole main but i dont think that this would help

Comment: @Barmar can i change this with c++ or should i open it extern and change the encoding?

Comment: You can't just change the encoding to remove double byte chars (they will get lost and displayed wrong), that's why you simply should read the file in binary mode byte by byte and remove the `\0` before processing the file. (I guess there are no valid `\0` in the file so just remove them all!?)

Comment: You have a file which has been written in UTF-16.  Either generated by a Windows or Java program.  If you are running on Windows, read the file with a wofstream.  If you read the values file into a std::wstring, you will be able to handle arbitrary Unicode characters.  (If you need to write out ASCII, I strongly recommend writing UTF-8 instead - this will look like ASCII if possible, and will still cope with arbitrary unicode.)

Comment: You are also playing with fire if you use characters like ö in your source - I would stick to 'oe' and 'ss'

Comment: Thank you all very much
Since Visual Studio Express 2015 seams to have a but with locale and codecvt for converting UTF-16 I solved it opening in a text editor and saving with new encoding.

@MartinBonner sadly i failed with you wstring solution. Maybe one day i'll understand it. Also thank you for mentioning the variable names i'll try to change them.